# How to handle something like [1,2,3] with html5 input type text?

Tags: html, regex, validation

I would like to know if we can handle specific input like the following examples using pattern:

[1] or
[1,2]

so basically brackets with a number or if there are more numbers then only comma allowed as a separator.

Tried [(\d+(\s*,?))+] as stated below but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do it:

```
^\[(?:\d+(?:,\d+)*)?\]$
```

- `^` - start line anchor
- `\[` - open literal square bracket
- `(?:` - open non-capturing group

  - `\d+` - one or more digits
  - `(?:` - open non-capturing group

    - `,\d+` - comma followed by one or more digits
  - `)` - close non-capturing group
  - `*` - match pattern inside non-capturing group zero or more times
- `)` - close non-capturing group
- `?` - make the preceding non-capturing group content optional; basically, allow for empty `[]`
- `\]` - close literal square bracket
- `$` - end line anchor

https://regex101.com/r/BuRsND/1

Comment: @Just_Do_It You're welcome. I've updated with an explanation.

Comment: what if I also need just [] along with other options as listed in my query?

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex `\[(\d+(\s*(,(?=\d))?))+\]`

Comment: @naveen I guess he would like to pass spaces as well

Comment: I tried this but didn't work

Comment: @naveen That allows a trailing comma; presumably undesirable.